# Disable front-end registrators from recving a confirmation email

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.3.x, joomla-api, joomla-framework-1.x

I'm trying to disable users that register from the front-end from receiving confirmation / welcome emails.

**Please note:**

1. In com_users options you can only disable the password and username from being sent but the email itself still generating.
2. When going to plugins manager -> user ->  Notification Mail to User -> No | it will only disable mailing to users who have been registered manually by the website admin.

I have seen a thread where they suggest a hack to components -> com_users -> contoller.php 
referance:
http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=280282

The problem is that they are suggesting this for an older version of Joomla! and the controller.php does not have those lines anymore (Not that i can see)

If the only way to achieve this is by hacking the core, so be it, although, i would prefer a 'clean' solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable it commenting line 510, components/com_users/models/registration.php.

```
    // Send the registration email.
    // $return = JFactory::getMailer()->sendMail($data['mailfrom'], $data['fromname'], $data['email'], $emailSubject, $emailBody);
```

**NOTE**: This is a core hack. It has to be re-implemented in every Joomla update.

Comment: +1. Nice solution, but it should be noted that this is a core hack, and could be overwritten when upgrading Joomla.

Comment: Txs, I have just added a note to the answer.